Ellipsis Not Working on lightning:button Label in Salesforce Lightning
I'm facing an issue with the text-overflow: ellipsis CSS property not working as expected on a lightning:button component in a Salesforce Lightning component. Below is the code snippet I'm using:
<div class="slds-size_2-of-3">
  <aura:if isTrue="{!empty(v.fieldApiName)}">
    <lightning:button variant="base" label="+" title="Select field" onclick="{! c.showModal }" />
    <aura:set attribute="else">
      <div style="overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;">
        <lightning:button variant="base" label="{!v.fieldApiName}" title="{!v.fieldApiName}" onclick="{! c.showModal }" />
      </div>
    </aura:set>
  </aura:if>
</div>

The lightning:button should display the v.fieldApiName with an ellipsis if the text is too long to fit within the button. However, the text is being truncated, but no ellipsis appears at the end of that truncated label.
I've wrapped the button in a div with:
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
white-space: nowrap;

but it doesn't seem to work.
Questions:
Is there a specific reason why the ellipsis isn't working for the lightning:button component?
Are there any known workarounds or best practices for achieving this in Lightning components?
Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions!

Try adding max-width: 100%

Hi Nick, I have also tried that



But eventhough , the ellipsis is not adding to the truncated field. the entire width is occupying with characters of truncated field only.

the only way i could get it to work was by putting an actual max-wdith on it, and setting display to inline-block.  max-width: 200px; display: inline-block;

Even that was also not worked Nick...
